# How can I correct the coding of an observation using R software?

Tags: r

In my dataset, male is represented by 1 and female is represented by 2. But there is another observation in the dataset by mistake, which is 3. I have checked the dataset and found that it will be 1 (male). How can I correct this mistake at the analysis stage, not in the dataset using r software?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and give a [mcve] in your question!

Answer (score 0):

This is done through indexing the data (`df`) based on the condition you want to replace (`sex == 3`) and reassigning:

```
df <- data.frame(sex = sample(1:3, 10, rep = T))
```

makes this data frame:

```
   sex
1    2
2    2
3    2
4    1
5    3
6    1
7    3
8    1
9    2
10   2
```

index and reassign

```
df$sex[df$sex == 3] <- 1
```

gives this:

```
   sex
1    2
2    2
3    2
4    1
5    1
6    1
7    1
8    1
9    2
10   2
```